# Only Enable Scrollbar on Body And Disable on Other Div with CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is there a way to only enable scrollbar on the body only and disable on other divs?

This code disables all scrollbar in everywhere:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none;
}
```

How to enable only on the body?

---

### EDITED

Changing overflow is not the one I want. Let's say I want to **create mobile friendly view editor**, which able to scroll up and down inside the div content but the scrollbar should be hidden. The scrollbar in the body is necessary because I will have to edit the view from my desktop web browser.

Changing overflow will not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

These two CSS properties can be used to hide the scrollbars:

```
#parent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/